# Background Image setup issue (GHWalkThrough library on github)

Tags: ios, objective-c

this is a walkthrough open library on github that I want to use in my app.

https://github.com/GnosisHub/GHWalkThrough

there is a method to set up bg view:

```
- (UIImage*) bgImageforPage:(NSInteger)index
{
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bgimage"];
    return image;
}
```

And I wanted to add set different image for each index, so i did this:

```
- (UIImage*) bgImageforPage:(NSInteger)index {

    UIImage* image;

    if (index == 0) {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"screen 1"];
    } else if (index == 1) {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"screen 2"];
    } else if (index == 2) {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"screen 3"];
    } else if (index == 3) {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"screen 4"];
    }

    return image;
}
```

Result:

whenever the view is loaded there is a clear bg, and if I swipe left to index 1 I get screen 1 > and if I swipe left for index 2, 3 & 4 the bg stays screen 1...

Can someone see what is wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried to set a breakpoint in that method and find out what index values do you receive? Does all the pictures provided really exists in your images assets?

Comment: does this code - (UIImage*) bgImageforPage:(NSInteger)index {UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"screen 1"];return image;} works fine for you with single image?

Answer (score 2):

i think you have minor mistak from code.

```
- (UIImage*) bgImageforPage:(NSInteger)index
{     
    NSString* imageName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bg_0%ld.jpg", index+1]; // you have manually add name but not increment index
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    return image;
}
```

if you can't use bottom code & use upper code you got your result or same as use bottom code & use upper code then also you got same result.

```
- (UIImage*) bgImageforPage:(NSInteger)index
{

    NSString* imageName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bg_0%ld.jpg", index+1];
    UIImage* image;// = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    if (index == 0) {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    } else if (index == 1) {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    } else if (index == 2) {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    } else if (index == 3) {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    }


    return image;
}
```

Please add image name in your app image folder like below.

**(Note: your image name set below as in your project.)**

**Example Image Name** :-

[image]

your condition wise you got new index but not getting images but when you set images name like same as upper images name & you got your images as index wise.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to update `index`, which means it stays at 0.

If it stays at 0, the image will always be `"screen 1"`.

Comment: it a delegate method that give me the index when the page swiped

Comment: Which means the index is not properly updated when  the page is swiped.

Comment: ok so i'd love to get some code example based on the code that i shared :) please help me its driving me crazy. also why is the first bg image is also clear? and where should i set it since the delegate method is only called when i swipe...and when I load the app the walkthrough is the first thing to see